# SQL: Conditional syntax error and mysql_fetch_object misuse

Tags: php, mysql, sql, object, fetch

I am trying to create a login system using SQL and PHP. I have a standard database with three fields: username, password, and authorization level. For some reason, when I test the code, the login fails, even though I am using the correct access level with the correct credentials. Before I added the access level checker to my PHP, the code was functional but now **it returns a login failed error**.

```
    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login-test.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 && $row->authlevel == "admin") {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: admin_index.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login-failed.php");
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Comment: why are you searching for the password, it should be hashed and not transmitted.  Such as find username, then compare.  You should also not use mysql nor should you put variables into the sql

Comment: `'; Select * from members where authLevel = "admin" limit 1 --`  there I just hacked your login system if this was my entry for your username.  Just saying.

Comment: there is so many mistakes with this sql, can i link you to a tutorial to make a proper login form with mysqli?

Comment: I'm guessing this is what is meant by SQL Injection? I will hash the passwords but I took out the md5 thing for testing purposes so I could see what was being passed to SQL but I'll put it back before release.

Comment: Ctc please, please do...

Comment: md5 is not secure, use at least a salted sha256 password, or php hash_password function.

Comment: I would use OOP for my logins, but since that would confuse you more, here is a basic guide:
http://click4knowledge.com/php-login-script-tutorial.html

Comment: Also I'm hosting on open shift, which doesn't work when using MYSQLi. Is it worth changing providers to use MYSQLi?

Comment: huh are you certain it doesn't support mysqli? what is your php version

Comment: @Bora - most likely you have duplicate user records.  `mysql_num_rows($result)` whats this value? more then one I suspect.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix there is only one user record in the DB as of now, and since it works without the authlevel part, I know for sure that there was only one record...

Comment: if you get this page `header("location: login-failed.php");` then this condition is failing `if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 && $row->authlevel == "admin")` which means what if you have the right authlevel?   This `mysql_num_rows($result) == 1` is not one or the authlevel is wrong, or both.  That is it.

Comment: I realize the condition is failing, but I can't figure out why for the life of me... I tried everything I know

Comment: `echo  'Users: '. mysql_num_rows($result);`  before that condition.

Comment: The only other possibility is this `admin` is not equal to `Admin` in php, nor is  space space admin, etc. It has to be exact match.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I'll give that a shot... One sec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115779/discussion-between-bora-and-artisiticphoenix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, use PDO or mysqli and prepared statements.  Someone can just put this in

```
  '; Select * from members where authLevel = "admin" limit 1 --
```

For `$username` and bang logged in as an admin.  This is why

```
 SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=''; Select * from members where authLevel = "admin" limit 1 -- AND password='ababsdf'
```

This is what you query becomes, and the `--` is the MySql way of commenting so anything after that is ignored.  Essentially I just told it to select a user with admin for the authLevel and limit it to one result.

**UPDATE**
As for the answer there is 2 possibility,

- 1 authLevel is wrong,
- 2 and more likely is you have duplicate user records.  So the number of rows check fails

Also `admin` is not the same as `Admin` or `ADMIN` or `[space]admin` with space.  String comparison in php is case sensitive.

Regardless that condition is failing, so one or both of the items in there are not true.  All you have to do is this

```
  echo 'NumRows: '.mysql_num_rows($result);
  echo "<br>\n";
  echo 'AuthLevel: '.$row->authlevel;
```

To tell, just output them and it should become fairly obvious.  Also comment out that header redirection ( so you don't get kicked out to that other page )

```
       //header("location: login-failed.php"); -- un-comment when fixed.
```

for authlevel you may want to wrap it in a bracket like this

```
    echo 'AuthLevel: ['.$row->authlevel.']';
```

Why? because if it's like this

```
    [  admin]
```

Then you can see there is a space or something in there.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to do this in your condition

```
    if( strtolower( trim( $row->authlevel ) ) == 'admin' ...
```

PDO or mysqli is really not that much harder you'd want to add a salt add encryption of at least sha256 ( or use password_hash() )  Basically your code would look like this

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=members;';
$user = 'db_user';
$password = '*******';

try {
    $DB = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=:username";  ///( add field named salt, this is a random string )
//search only for username 

///$DB is pdo database object
//prepare the sql, this 2 step process prevent sql injection by using a placeholder :username instead of the variable directly
$stmt = $DB->prepare( $qry );
 //execute the statement with variables
$stmt->execute( array(':username' => $username ) );
//retrieve the result row as an object.
$row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($stmt->rowCount() == 1 ) {
    if($row->authlevel == "admin") {  //if it's not an admin no need to check password
        if( sha256( $row->salt() . $password ) == $row->password ){
             //Check password in php, db is case insensitive unless its a binary field.
            //Login Successful ( obviously youll want to update the member to account for a better password )
            .....
        }else{
            header("location: login-failed.php"); //change for bad password etc.
        }
    } else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: login-failed.php");  //change for invalid user level ( you do not have authorization to view this page ... etc. )
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed"); //change for username not found, or unknown username
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

On top of the security reasons as of PHP7 mysql_* function are gone, so best to not get used to using them.

Comment: tbh this does not answer the question, but its a good point nonetheless.

Comment: Agreed, but of course this is important for the security of the protected area.

Comment: The question is impossible to answer, obviously the authLevel is wrong.  the num_rows is superficial, the check for that would never happen on no result,  There are 2 possibilities

Comment: Also, note the password comparison is done in PHP (not MySQL). MySQL queries are case-iinsensitive by default.

Comment: @SaadImran - by default yes but not if you use `utf8_bin` for the charset, but I updated the comments to mention that.  It's unlikely to get hash collisions but it's still better to use PHP, It's also important to not transport the hashed password, it may help compromise your encryption by giving away the hashing method used.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix ahh never came across that, thanks for the info :)

Comment: Sure, you can also do LIKE BINARY, for the same effect.  MySql will then use the Unicode character to do the comparison.  But as I mentioned you give away the hashing method used by transmitting the hashed data.  For example if I see a hashed 32 bit string in the post I can just hash what I put in ( with md5 ) and tell if it's salted or not.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Just for informational purposes. Wouldn't the query transport the hashed password column anyway so it can help compromise your encryption?

Comment: It does but it doesn't help a hacker because what was hashed to get the password originally in not known ( so you couldn't tell with just that if it was salted ), however I would know what I put in the form.  Also it's done on the mysql port and not port 80, so it wont show as easily.  And even if they can see the salt for the password in the mysql transmission it would be harder to figure out where it was added, before or after, because again they don't know the original data.  Essentially, with the original data and the hash you can figure out the methods used.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: Once you know how it's encrypted, and have the salt you can build a rainbow table using that salt.  But even with the salt you'd need to figure out how the salt was added  ( salt . password ) ( salt .password .salt ) ( password .salt ) etc.  I like to add a random length string to the password and then just substring it off in php just to mess with people.  I've even dropped a random length string in the middle of the encrypted password, and then pulled it back out in php : )

Comment: @SaadImran. Sure as far as security goes never give information away, the less someone knows about your encryption methods the harder it is to reverse engineer it.  Ideally you want it to be to the point that they have to gain access to your php code, to figure it out because at that point it doesn't really matter anymore ( once they have access to the server's filesystem you have bigger issues )